# CSS: How can i divide a border into two lines?

Tags: html, css

This is something i am trying to do-

[image]

I know creating a box in css is easy and giving any side of border is more easy. But how can i get this shape using css only.

However i tried this something, All i could do it with using two divs (One with white background).

I tried-

**CSS**

```
.box
{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border:10px solid #111;

    z-index:1;

}
h1
{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;

}
.transparent-border
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    height:20px;
    width:170px;

    left:30px;
    background:white;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="transparent-border"></div>
<div class="box"><h1>ABC</h1>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE**

[Border division](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/Gasdj/7/)

Comment: Have you looked at the border-image property?

Comment: Just google for "css border bracket", you'll find a lot of solutions.

Comment: why mark as duplicate if there isn't an accepted answer on the duplicate... anyways you all most had it with the transparent div, i updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gasdj/17/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is easy solution with :before and :after pseudoelements.

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9f2d/)

```
.box:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px; 
    left:10%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    width:80%;
    background:white;
}

.box:after {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px; 
    left:10%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    width:80%;
    background:white;
}
```

You assign `position:relative` to the div.box. Then assign `position:absolute to` `:before` and `:after` elements. Then apply white background and use top and bottom to place it on the black border. The height of pseudoelements has to be equal with border width of box.div.

Comment: Not that i assumed but by far best solution i've got.

Comment: Other solutions that comes to my mind is to use `border-image` property BUT: 1) it is not supported by older browsers 2) creating that image can be very tricky 3) Solution above will work in most cases, when with `border-image`, you'll have to adjust css to specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

**html:** only one `div`

```
<div class="border">
    <h1>ABC</h1>
</div>
```

**css:** white `background-color` and negative `margin`

```
.border
{
    border:10px solid #111;
    width:200px;
}

h1
{
    background-color: white;  /* most important part */
    margin: -10px 10px;       /* most important part */

    text-align:center;

    padding: 20px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xWmky/1/)

Answer (score 0):

increase the height of the transparent boarder and push the text to the top:

```
.box {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border:10px solid #111;
    z-index:1;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;     
}
.transparent-border {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    height:120px;
    width:170px;   
    left:30px;
    background:white;  
}
```

Comment: this is i have already tried, is there any other trick without using another div?

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
<style type="text/css">
  .b:after{content:"]"}
  .b:before{content:"["}
</style>

<span class="b">text</span>
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ9Mt/)

Answer (score 0):

If your background has a solid color, there's an easy way.

The inner element has a solid BG color and is being pulled over the outer element's border with negative, vertical margins. But you also give the inner element some horizontal margins, so the outer element's border ends up looking like brackets:

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">ABC</div>
</div>


.outside {
    border:10px solid #111;
    display:inline-block;
}
.inside {
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    margin:-10px 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gasdj/11/

The pseudoelement solution breaks on multi-line text.